# Pass dynamic object to common method for Post data in Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

In my application, it is calling webapi, and application is in MVC5. Now I have many more methods in application project. So I want to create one common(global) method to call the api. Methods which are used for get content those are working fine, but methods, those are used to post(means save data to DB kind of) data, getting error like this. Code is like below:

```
public static string SendDataToAPI(dynamic objCommon, string urlParameters, ref string errorMessage)
{
    try {
        string url = ConfigurationSettingHelper._BaseUrl;
        string strJson = string.Empty;
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(urlParameters, objCommon);

            if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                strJson = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else {
                errorMessage = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }

            return strJson;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
        return errorMessage;
    }
}
```

So, my question is how can I pass dynamic object type in `PostAsJsonAsync` method? How can I set this kind of method for common use?

Comment: you can create an anonymous object like - `var employee = {Name =  "James", Age = 30 };` and convert it to JSON using Newtonsoft and pass it to `PostAsJsonAsync`

Answer (score 1):

Try something below where the post data model generically accepts any type and complex object also should be wrapped into single model.

```cs
public async virtual Task<string> ExecuteHttpApiCall<TModel>(TModel model, string url)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);
        }
        else
        {
            response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        }
    
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```